# Error:Kotlin: Multiple values are not allowed for plugin option org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt:output

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a fairly big project used kotlin version 1.0.5 and dagger1, this is the error that I'm getting after kotlin upgrade to 1.1.1 when I build the project from within the intellij IDE by clicking the ***build project*** button:

```
Error:Kotlin: Multiple values are not allowed for plugin option org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt:output
Plugin "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" usage:
  annotations <path>         Annotation filter regular expressions, separated by commas
  output <path>              File in which annotated declarations will be placed
  stubs <path>               Output path for stubs
  inherited <true/false>     True if collecting Kotlin class names for inherited annotations is needed
```

Strangely the command line gradle build works just fine without any complains.

Is it a intellij kotlin plugin bug?

Comment: Sound like the problem from this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16888 (already fixed in Kotlin 1.1.2).

Comment: @yanex, I've tried the dev build with the fix, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like a bug. Can you please create a new issue with some additional details in our bug tracker (http://kotl.in/issue)?

Comment: @yanex, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16965